# Perl - grep in foreach does not work with $_ but was with variable

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach, grep

I want to delete some defined elements from a array. I already have a solution with `grep` and one element: `@big = grep { ! /3/ } @big`. In case of several elements I want to put them in an array and using foreach. `@big` is the array from which I want delete elements from `@del`:

```
perl -e "@big = (1,2,3,4,5); @del = (2,4); 
      foreach $i (@del) {@big = grep { ! /$i/ } @big; print \"@big\n\"}"
```

Here is the output:

```
1 3 4 5
1 3 5
```

This works fine for me. If I want to use default variable `$_` it does not work:

```
perl -e "@big = (1,2,3,4,5); @del = (2,4); 
      foreach (@del) {@big = grep { ! /$_/ } @big; print \"@big\n\"}"
```

This gives no output. Any idea what happens?

Comment: `foreach` and `grep` both clobber `$_`. And if you re-assign `@big` on every iteration, your code probably isn't doing what you want anyway!

Comment: @MattJacob why not? it deletes one element at every iteration over `@del` (or more, if more elements are matching). it might not be the fastest solution, but it's correct

Comment: @tinita Oops, you're right. That's what I get for browsing SO and trying to cook for Thanksgiving at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MattJacob points out, there are two conflicting uses for `$_`:

```
foreach (@del) {...}
```

This implicitly uses `$_` as the loop variable. From the [foreach](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) docs:

> The foreach keyword is actually a synonym for the for keyword, so you can use either. If VAR is omitted, $_ is set to each value.

Your `grep` command also uses `$_`, **always**, as part of its processing. So if you had a value in `$_` as part of your `foreach`, and it was replaced in the `grep` ...?

From the [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) docs:

> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally setting $_ to each element)

Please do check the grep docs, since there is an explicit warning about modifying a list that you are iterating over. If you are trying to iteratively shrink the list, you might consider some alternative ways to process it. (For example, could you build a single pattern for `grep` that would combine all the values in your `@del` list, and just process the `@big` list one time? This might be quicker, too.)

Comment: Thanks! If I had a look at the foreach or grep docs I would have avoid to use `$_`. The advantage to put the question on SO is that you suggest to do this task in another way. What do you mean with *build a single pattern for*? Is that a regular expression which match all elements of `@del`? For exampe, `$del = '2|4'` and then: `@big = grep { ! /$del/ } @big;`. This is a good idea and so simple. It is embarassing not to get it myself. Interesting would be how to cope if putting in a pattern is not possible.

Comment: yeah, it might be confusing with other similar syntax `if (grep { $_ eq $element } @list) {` where however the $_ variable represents also as here, the inner symbol, not the one passed for example when passed inside from another additional  map